# Create UI like Provisioning Profile Detail view in iPhone itself.

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, ios5, interface-builder, custom-controls

I want to create UI in my application same as, iOS uses in

```
Settings > General > Profiles > Profiles > (final view with remove button)
```

Any Suggestions? As I am not sure that it's readymade tool or madeup using different controls!!!
If I have to make it using controls provided by IB, from where should i start ??
I also want to add a button to add the detail to contacts(or say AddressBook).

I appreciate if someone can provide me answer with details.
Thanks.

Comment: Can we get an example screenshot? I have no profiles to remove currently on my iPhone.

Comment: @DylanGattey: Sorry, was running out of time. But Problem got solved with the answer of H2CO3. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a long time ago I had a provisioning profile on my iPhone, but I can remember that basically it was just an UITableView with images and text in its cells. You can simply use a custom subclass of UITableViewController of type UITableViewTypeGrouped and use the UITableViewDataSource or UITableViewDelegate methods to customiz the cells' appearance (you will generally want a cell of UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle). You may also add UIBarButtonItems to the view controllers navigationItem property and wrap the view controller in an UINavigationController to get buttons on the top navigation bar.

Comment: Good answer. For the cell it could be much easier to create the cells in a xib file and load them in cellForRowAtIndexPath: instead of customizing it in the code.

Comment: @Pierre: but there is no fix number of cell, i need to create it dynamically depending on the response i get from webservice.

Comment: You can reload the cell from the xib for each row. An Example `static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Identifier";
 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = (UITableViewCell*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
  
    }`